# Why does laravel work on browser but fails on phpunit tests?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

The title says it all. I have a feature of my code that is working in the browser but not in the tests.

So i im using laravel and phpunit. With phpunit i am trying to test the capability of the app change the state of a certain certificate object also call as "Atestado".

```
class Atestado extends Model implements HasMedia
{
use InteractsWithMedia;

protected $fillable = [
    /* Por Padrão */
    'tipo', 'estado',
    'atestado_da_situacao_economica_destina_a', 'atestado_da_situcao_economica_indicacoes_uteis',
    'created_at', 'updated_at',
];

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','atestado_user')->withPivot('tipo','created_at','updated_at');
}

public function pessoas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoa');
}

}
```

with the help of updateStatus method of AtestadoDaSituacaoEconomicaController

```
    public function updateStatus(Request $request, Atestado $atestado_da_situacao_economica){
    $user = auth()->user();

    if($user->hasRole('User')){
        if($request->has('estado')){
            switch($request->input('estado')){
                case 'Completo':
                    $atestado_da_situacao_economica->fill(['estado' => 'Completo']);
                    $atestado_da_situacao_economica->save();

                    $funcionarios = User::with('roles')->get()->reject(function ($user, $key){
                        return $user->hasRole('Funcionário');
                    });

                    foreach($funcionarios as $funcionario){
                        $detalhes = [
                            'texto' => 'O freguês deu o Atestado da Situação Económica como completo.',
                            'user_id' => $user->id,
                        ];

                        $funcionario->notify(new FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica($detalhes));
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }elseif($user->hasRole('Funcionário')){

    }

    return redirect(route('users.atestados.atestado-da-situacao-economica.index'));
}
```

The method is accessible trought the route:

```
    Route::put('/atestado-da-situacao-economica/{atestado_da_situacao_economica}/updateStatus', 'AtestadoDaSituacaoEconomicaController@updateStatus')->name('users.atestados.atestado-da-situacao-economica.updateStatus');
```

The test i am using is this one:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Notifications\FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Faker;

class AtestadoTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $atestado, $user_user, $user_funcionario, $role_user, $role_funcionario;

    public function setUp() :void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->atestado = factory('App\Atestado')->state('Atestado da Situação Económica Incompleto')->create();

        $this->user_user = factory('App\User')->state('Freguês')->create();

        $this->role_user = Role::create(['name' => 'User']);

        $this->user_user->assignRole($this->role_user);

        $this->user_funcionario = factory('App\User')->state('Funcionário')->create();

        $this->role_funcionario = Role::create(['name' => 'Funcionário']);

        $this->user_funcionario->assignRole($this->role_funcionario);

        $this->atestado->users()->attach([$this->user_user->id, $this->user_funcionario->id]);
    }

/** @test */
public function um_atestado_notifica_todos_os_funcionarios_assim_que_o_estado_muda_de_incompleto_para_completo(){
    $user_funcionario_ii = factory('App\User')->state('Funcionário')->create();

    $user_funcionario_ii->assignRole($this->role_funcionario);

    Notification::fake();

    $this->actingAs($this->user_user)
        ->put(route('users.atestados.atestado-da-situacao-economica.updateStatus', $this->atestado->id),array(
            'estado' => 'Completo'
        ))
        ->assertRedirect('atestado-da-situacao-economica');

    $this->atestado = $this->atestado->fresh();

    $this->assertTrue($this->atestado->estado == 'Completo');

    /*
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('notifications', [
       'type' => 'App\Notifications\FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica',
       'notifiable_type' => 'App\User',
       'notifiable_id' => '2',
       'data' => '{"data":"O fregu\u00eas deu o Atestado da Situa\u00e7\u00e3o Econ\u00f3mica como completo.","user_id":1}',
    ]);
    */

    $this->refreshInMemoryDatabase();

    Notification::assertSentTo($this->user_funcionario, FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica::class);
    Notification::assertSentTo($user_funcionario_ii, FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica::class);
}
```

It failing asserTrue ($this->assertTrue($this->atestado->estado == 'Completo');).

The notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $details;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * @param $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->details['texto'],
            'user_id' => $this->details['user_id'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**Using Xdebug the value as correctly change inside the controller but when it gets to the lines of code in test enviroment the value "estado" do not change at all.**

Anyone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: also tried $this->assertDatabaseHas('notifications', [
           'type' => 'App\Notifications\FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica',
           'notifiable_type' => 'App\User',
           'notifiable_id' => '2',
           'data' => '{"data":"O fregu\u00eas deu o Atestado da Situa\u00e7\u00e3o Econ\u00f3mica como completo.","user_id":1}',
        ]);

Comment: table is empty!

Comment: Are you using the RefreshDatabase trait in your Test Class?

Comment: The model object does not stay in sync with the table automatically. If you change it in the controller then you need to refetch it via e.g. `$this->atestado->refresh()`

Comment: You are `actingAs($this->user_user)` instead of the user you are creating in the `$user_funcionario_ii` variable, is that intended? Does the `$this->user_user` have the required roles?

Comment: @OsDev just by using RefreshDatabase Trait from (namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Testing) ir wont work...

Comment: @ChinLeung it is intend to be like that i am testing that in fact all staff recives a notification...

Comment: Ok so you can confirm the user have the correct roles? Then just as @apokryfos said, you need to refresh your instance with `$this->atestado->refresh()`.

Comment: @apokryfos edited the post... i was already using it ($this->atestado->fresh()) witch by the way is not related with the state of notifications...

Comment: @ChinLeung sorry edited so there is enought information...yes i confirm all users have the proper role...

Comment: Can you add a `dd()` in your switch case to see if the request gets there?

Comment: im so sorry stackoverflow as brilliant way to keep the post before is posted in cache but you have to edit your self dohh!

Comment: yes @ChinLeung the request works like charm it even goes to $funcionario->notify(new FuncionarioAtestadoDaSituacaoEconomica($detalhes)); line without any issue...

Comment: Did you test the `dd` with the test case or the browser though?

Comment: @ChinLeung i am using xdebug... i suppose i dont need dd() i am using in both enviroments testing and browser...

Comment: Yeah I know. What I mean is have you tested to make sure that when you are sending the request in your test environment it gets to the `->notify` line or only made sur it gets there when submitting via the browser?

Comment: @ChinLeung it gets to the **->notify** in both (states/enviroments) test or browser... so where it never gets is to **public function toDatabase($notifiable)** i will post the notification class...

Comment: Hmmm... Do you think you could make a repo on GitHub with the related code so I could test it on my end? Or add all the classes, factories and migrations to the question.

Comment: I do not have Skype and it's easier for me to test on my end if I could reproduce it on my side.